# Query: I dont understand this piece of code

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to ask for help in understanding this piece of code... Am a beginner to mysql so I found it hard to read what this code does...

```
SELECT b.bcode
FROM (SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items
      UNION
      SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items_bulk
     ) b left outer join
     tbl_reservation r
     on b.bcode = r.bcode and
        @USERTO <= r.ToDate and
        @USERFROM >= r.FromDate
WHERE r.bcode is null;
```

Would someone help me understand what this code does?
Thanks in advance!

@Ashutosh Arya, I was trying to get all the items that hasn't been reserved for a date and timespan. By being 'reserved', an equipment should be present in tbl_reservations. I'm just trying to get the opposite of getting all the equipment for a certain date and timespan.

Logic:

1. get all the equipment bcode currently present in tbl_items, tbl_items_bulk(UNION).
2. get all the equipment bcode currently present in tbl_reservations and see if there are matches with the UNION in number 1.
3. if there are matches, filter the results further using the resDate(reservation date).
   **this results in NOT displaying all the bcodes that has the resDate that the user specified.
4. if there are still matches, filter the results further using the timeSTART and timeEND.

meaning to say,
-if an equipment bcode exists in the tbl_reservations, DO NOT DISPLAY IT.
-if an equipment bcode exists in the tbl_reservations, but doesn't have the resDate the user will specify, then SHOW it.
-if an equipment bcode exists in the tbl_reservations, has the resDate the user will specify, but doesn't have the time covered by timeStart and timeEnd, then SHOW IT.

It seems like my code only checks for a date.
I was thinking of something that checks for date and time as well, like:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_items
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM tbl_items_bulk
     ) b left outer join
     tbl_test t
     on b.bcode = t.bcode and
        '2013-09-16' = t.resDate AND
        '9:30' <= t.timeSTART AND
        '7:00' >= t.timeEND
WHERE t.bcode is null;
```

AND ALSO, my system doesn't allow borrowing equipment for a long period of time. Anyone cannot borrow an equipment for more than 7:00AM-9:00PM(15 Hours).

HERE's the LATEST code(timeFROM and timeTO changed to timeSTART and timeEND because my system doesn't allow more than 15hours of reservation a day and does not allow reservation for more than 1 day):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_items
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM tbl_items_bulk
     ) b left outer join
     tbl_test t
     on b.bcode = t.bcode and
     NOT ('4:30' < t.timeSTART OR '7:00' > t.timeEND)
WHERE t.bcode is null;
```

Comment: What actually you don't understand? `UNION`, `JOIN`, nested query, user variables `@VAR`?

Comment: The purpose of @VAR in this query is one of the things I don't understand.

Comment: It is finding all records that are present in table tbl_items, between two dates _USERTO and _USERFROM, The union kind of seems redundant

Comment: Hmm. with the UNION, I was kinda saying to my database: "get all the rows from both the tables". Redundant? What do you mean?

Comment: Apologies i thought table outside is same , can you tell me what is the business meaning of table tbl_reservation , and i guess tbl_items & tbl_items_bulk hold meaning of two type of orders. right ?

Comment: @AshutoshArya, tbl_reservation is the table responsible for storing the details of the reservation like time, date, what equipment is borrowed, who borrowed it. And tbl_items and tbl_items_bulk contains all my equipment. Like an inventory of stuff...

Comment: @user2784251 So your query is finding the stuff that is currently present in the inventory for reservation or borrow. Please correct me if am wrong , the process must be like this a record is entered in tbl_reservation once someone borrows an equipment, what this querrys is doing here is first finding list of all the items buy union, then joining them with tbl_reservation on bcode and where condition saying all those items which are present in you union(the inventory) and not present in borrow list(tbl_reservation).means the list of all items present currently in your inventory for reservation

Comment: Be mindful though, your query does not return the correct collection. Imagine this: A user wants to reserve item with code 3 from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-11. Item 3 has an outstanding reservation from 2013-01-04 to 2013-01-14. This item will not be filtered out, since USERTO (2013-01-11) <= r.ToDate (2013-01-14)  but not USERFROM (2013-01-01) >= r.FromDate (2013-01-04). So no match in the join and thus item 3 will be in the result set, even though it is not available for the full reservation time. You need to change the condition so that it will also filter out partial matches in the timespan.

Comment: @Anton, I apologize because this is taking longer time than I thought. I'm clueless as to how to do that, I mean, I know I need to add another condition, but I dont know how to start.

Comment: Usually there's a pretty easy boolean solution, you invert the condition and negate it. All reservations that have a ToDate smaller than USERFROM are no problem, so are all reservations that have a FromDate larger than USERTO. Then negate that: so the join condition becomes: "on b.bcode = r.bcode and NOT (USERTO < r.FromDate OR USERFROM > r.ToDate)". Haven't tested it though :)

Comment: How will it go if for example, i won't allow borrowing equipment for more than 15 hours a day? I mean, equipment are to be returned that same day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll try explain, hope you understand it;

```
SELECT b.bcode                     // Selecting the bCode from tbl_items and tbl_items_bulk
    FROM (SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items
          UNION
          SELECT bcode FROM tbl_items_bulk
         ) b left outer join           // join to tbl_reservation where the bcode is equal and in
                                          a given timespan (USERTO  & USERFROM are 2 variables 
                                          passed from outside)
    tbl_reservation r
     on b.bcode = r.bcode and
        @USERTO <= r.ToDate and
        @USERFROM >= r.FromDate
WHERE r.bcode is null;            // and where your selected bcode is equal to null
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still wondering what purpose does "WHERE r.bcode is null;" serve in my code..

Comment: It effectively filters out anything with matches in tbl_reservation table. Since you have a left join on b.code=r.code any row with r.code=NULL means that there was not a matching row in tbl_reservation.

Comment: @RealityGone, by filtering you meant it will not display anything that HAS a match in the tbl_reservation? or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: That is correct, as long as you realize that "having a match" is restricted to "having a match within the given timespan".

Comment: @Anton, so, meaning to say, the 'criteria' for having a 'match' is that the reservation must occur during the given timespan, and if it doesnt occur during the given timespan, it would be displayed(it would show as 'available')?

Answer (score 2):

Effectively your query is showing you all of the bcode values from the tables `tbl_items` and `tbl_bulk_items` that do not have a match in the bcode column of the `tbl_reservations` table.

This query could be done more effeciently as so:

```
SELECT t.bcode 
FROM (
    SELECT bcode
    FROM tbl_items
    UNION
    SELECT bcode
    FROM tbl_items_bulk
) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_reservation AS r
    WHERE r.bcode=t.bcode
        AND r.toDate>='20130916 07:00:00' AND r.fromDate<='20130916 22:00:00'
)
```

Comment: But what if the I need to check if those bcodes present in the tbl_reservation is only for a certain date and timespan?(e.g. 2013-09-16 from 7AM to 10AM)?

Comment: You would add the time filtering to the NOT EXISTS() subquery. That way it is only checking the tbl_reservation bcodes for that range. (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

result of this code is nothing, because this case `on b.bcode = r.bcode` is exception of `WHERE r.bcode is null;`

Comment: What do you mean by "is exception of WHERE r.bcode is null;"? From vb.net, exceptions are errors right? Is it the same here?

Comment: @Anton, what do you mean by "It's a left outer join..."? I know what a left outer join is but am not quite sure what you meant...

Comment: I meant that he either seems to have misread the query properly or not understand the left outer join. The query actually will return a result. It will return all code values for item or item_bulk records that have no entries in tbl_reservation during the interval passed in using the two @User variables. Unless I am mistaken, ofcourse.

Comment: @Anton, i understand. The code is for something like a query that tries to find what equipment is available for a certain date and time...